# How to make vue-routes works

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to setup routes with tutorial. I have this code but any data not imports to the selected page(/home). Any idea how to fix it? This is my code:

App.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import router from "./router";
import App from "./components/App";
import Test from "./components/test";
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render : h => h(App),
    router
});
@endsection
```

pastebin:
    https://pastebin.com/7yMREHxR

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-browser-hsi6d

Comment: Welcome to SO! we are going to need a lot more information to help. What tutorial are you following and can you show us the code for you main.js and routes.js. If you are unsure you can try and replicate your problem in a (CodeSandbox)[https://codesandbox.io/] for us to look at.

Comment: Pastebin link was attached to the post. There is all information you asks.

Comment: there is tutorial i trying to repeat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRGhohwRPe8

Comment: Hey Dora28noFake, from what I understood of your question I tried to answer it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Test from "./components/Test";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/home",
      component: Test
    }
  ]
});
```

to

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Test from "./components/Test";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: Test
    }
  ]
});
```

The key take away here is the path property. You set it to "/home". So your app worked but only when you navigated to "localhost:xxxx/home/" by changing it to "/" it becomes your root view. Check out this sand box to play with the solution:

[image: Edit Answer for Dora28noFake]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, seems like i have some problems on local.